# Downloading an attachment. Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to download an attachment in VB.NET but getting an error as follows:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

My Code:

```
Protected Sub DownloadFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(TryCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    Dim fileName As String, contentType As String
    strQry = "select file_name, license_doc, file_type from Driver_Mas where Id=" & Val(id)

    Reader = Osql.ExecuteRead(strQry)
    While Reader.Read
        bytes = DirectCast(Reader.Item("license_doc"), Byte())            
        contentType = Reader.Item("file_type").ToString()
        fileName = Reader.Item("file_name").ToString()
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = contentType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("license_doc")` to get bytes from a string. You can change UTF8 to any other encoding if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Encoding.GetBytes` method to get bytes from a string. You can change UTF8 to any other encoding if necessary

```
bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reader.Item("license_doc"))
```

Comment: He don't want to convert the string `"license_doc"` but the content of the Reader for the item "license_doc". So the correct use should be `bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reader.Item("license_doc"))`

Comment: @equisde oh sorry missed it. fixed in updated answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: umm.. your edit is kind of incorrect.. the method is `Encoding.[SomeEncoding].GetBytes`.

Comment: The edit is correct. The name of the method is [**Encoding.GetBytes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx). Your proposal by using `[SomeEncoding]` which is a [**property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) is used when overridden in a derived class.

Comment: yes you are right. [Some Encoding] belongs to the class Encoding and thus `Encoding.GetBytes`. The way of using it is `Encoding.[Some Encoding].GetBytes()` sorry for the confusion (and misunderstanding your edit).

Comment: No worries at all. Everyday's a school day ;-)